# Understanding `sequence` with `[[a]]` Monad

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
Prelude>[ [Just 10, Just 20], [Just 5] ]
[ [Just 10, Just 20], [Just 5] ]
```

it has type:

```
Prelude> :t [ [Just 10, Just 20], [Just 5] ]
[ [Just 10, Just 20], [Just 5] ] :: Num a => [[Maybe a]]
```

I'd like to apply this to `sequence`:

```
Prelude> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

The `Monad m` in the above List is: `[a]`, as I understand, so I'd expect the types to line up as:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
                       [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Assuming that's right, then please help me understand the output:

```
Prelude> sequence [ [Just 10, Just 20], [Just 5] ]
[[Just 10,Just 5],[Just 20,Just 5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to do this with just `Int`s instead of `Maybe Int`s:

```
> sequence [[10, 20], [5]]
[[10,5],[20,5]]
it :: [[Int]]
```

The type signature you deduced is correct, it does have type `[[a]] -> [[a]]` in this situation, where `a ~ Int` in my example or `a ~ Maybe Int` in your example.  Whenever using `sequence` in the list monad, I like to think of it as an N-dimensional Cartesian product.  It desugars to something like

```
sequence [a, b, c] = do
    x <- a
    y <- b
    z <- c
    return [x, y, z]
```

But with an arbitrary number of elements, not just 3.  Some other examples might help explain:

```
sequence [["a1", "a2", "a3"], ["b1", "b2"], ["c1", "c2", "c3"]]
[
  ["a1","b1","c1"],["a1","b1","c2"],["a1","b1","c3"],["a1","b2","c1"],["a1","b2","c2"],["a1","b2","c3"],
  ["a2","b1","c1"],["a2","b1","c2"],["a2","b1","c3"],["a2","b2","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a2","b2","c3"],
  ["a3","b1","c1"],["a3","b1","c2"],["a3","b1","c3"],["a3","b2","c1"],["a3","b2","c2"],["a3","b2","c3"]
]
```

If you study this output closely, you'll see that we have each element of the `a`s matched with each element of the `b`s and each element from the `c`s.  Since there are 3 `a`s, 2 `b`s, and 3 `c`s, there are `3*2*3 == 18` elements in the output.

Answer (score 3):

What `sequence` does is to turn something like

```
[foo, bar, baz]
```

into something like

```
do
  x <- foo
  y <- bar
  z <- baz
  return [x, y, z]
```

In your case, we have

```
do
  x <- [Just 10, Just 5]
  y <- [Just 5]
  return [x, y]
```

which is the same as

```
foreach x in [Just 10, Just 5]
  foreach y in [Just 5]
    return [x, y]
```

in psuedo-OO syntax.

It should now be fairly obvious why you get the result you do.